# Problems with MongoDB csv upload

Tags: mongodb, csv

I'm trying to import a `csv` file into `MongoDB` and running into `"Unexpected Identifier"` error.

```
 mongoimport –-db projectexperiment -—collection structured_1000 --type csv --file /dataset/structured/structured_1000.csv --headerline
```

Am quite new to MongoDB and was wondering if some one could point me in the right direction

Comment: Please reduce your CSV file to the line which causes the error and post that one line of the file.

Comment: Are you running mongoimport from the terminal  ? And not from the mongo shell ?

Comment: @JacodeGroot I was running it through the shell I think, it was connected to "test"

Comment: Run it from terminal

Comment: @Sekai Sorry to ask but how do you access the terminal? Is it through cmd?

Comment: The terminal is the instance where you run `mongo` 
what's your OS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run mongoimport from the terminal. Assuming you are using Windows, you need to start a DOS prompt (cmd) go to the bin directory of your mongodb installation and run your monogimport command:

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport –-db projectexperiment -—collection structured_1000 --type csv --file /dataset/structured/structured_1000.csv --headerline
```

Comment: From this answer i'm seeing `unknown option -u` error.

Comment: I will double check later this evening, but is a strange error mesage as I can't see the option -u

Comment: I checked `dbhelp` and it said something about `-u` relating to the username.